# Convert threeten LocalDate to YearMonth

Tags: java, date, java-time

I have a `LocalDate` which I need to convert to `YearMonth`. 
I am using ThreeTen API (Backport of JSR-310 to Java SE 7). 
Is there anyway I can do this?

I tried this in Joda-Time but in ThreeTen it is not offered.

```
LocalDate date;
new YearMonth(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear());
```

Answer (score 45):

Looking at the doc [YearMonth api](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/YearMonth.html), try:

```
YearMonth myYearMonth = YearMonth.from(localDate);
```

Comment: Direct URL to [*YearMonth*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/YearMonth.html) in ThreeTen documentation.

Comment: @Squizer, your URL is broken, I've edited it. Please update it again if it is not the one that you wanted.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Thank you

Answer (score 3):

These commands all result in equal `YearMonth` values:

```
YearMonth.from(localDate)

localDate.query(YearMonth.FROM) // ThreeTen
localDate.query(YearMonth::from) // JDK 8

YearMonth.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonth())

YearMonth.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue())
```